# Generic classes in Java (type-safely) depending on each other

Tags: java, generics, types

I want to create an abstract collection class (called Space) and an
abstract element class (called Atom). Instances of both have to know each other (exactly typed).
That's the problem.

```
abstract class Space<A extends Atom>{
  // ...
}

abstract class Atom<S extends Space>{
  // ...
}
```

Not good:

"A extends Atom" means any Atom, but not a strongly typed one

"S extends Space" means any Space, but not a strongly typed one

I can't reach complete type-safety with the following attempts either:

```
abstract class Space<A extends Atom<? extends Space>>
abstract class Atom<S extends Space<? extends Atom>>

abstract class Space<S, A extends Atom<S extends Space<A>>>
abstract class Atom<A, S extends Space<A extends Atom<S>>>

and so on ...
```

**Remember, these two classes are abstract, and I want that any possible
two subclasses are typed according to each other.**
That means, the classes SomeSpace and SomeAtom in the following example
must have a strong "type knowledge" of each other:

```
class SomeSpace extends Space<SomeAtom>
class SomeAtom extends Atom<SomeSpace>
```

Comment: Ok I'll bite.. why are you doing this? :) Is this your actual abstraction or is it just an example for the question?

Comment: please see my own `answer` for real code example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me, although I got really confused about all those generic constraints. Which means I can't guarantee that it does what it's supposed to do:

```
interface ISpace<S extends ISpace<S, A>, A extends IAtom<S, A>> {
        List<? extends IAtom<S, A>> getList(); //// CHANGED
}

interface IAtom<S extends ISpace<S, A>, A extends IAtom<S, A>> {
        S getSpace();
}

abstract class Space<S extends Space<S, A>, A extends Atom<S, A>>
                implements ISpace<S, A> {

        private final List<Atom<S, A>> atoms = new LinkedList<Atom<S, A>>(); ////CHANGED

        public Space() {
        }
        public Space<S, A> getSpace() {
                return this;
        }
        @Override
        public List<Atom<S, A>> getList() {  //// CHANGED
                return atoms;
        }
}

abstract class Atom<S extends Space<S, A>, A extends Atom<S, A>>
                implements IAtom<S, A> {

        private final S space;

        public Atom(S someSpace) {
                this.space = someSpace;
                space.getList().add(this);
        }

        @Override
        public S getSpace() {
                return space;
        }

        public Atom<S, A> getAtom() {
                return this;
        }
}

class Space1 extends Space<Space1, Atom1> {
        public Space1() {
        }
}

class Atom1 extends Atom<Space1, Atom1> {
        public Atom1(Space1 someSpace) {
                super(someSpace);
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works also, thank you!

So the 'secret' is to override getList() with a more concrete type than the interface defines.

Answer (score 3):

```
abstract class Space<S extends Space<S,A>, A extends Atom <A, S>> {}
abstract class Atom <A extends Atom <A,S>, S extends Space<S, A>> {}
```

Or, I guess, if you prefer

```
abstract class Space<S extends Space<S,A>, A extends Atom<S, A>> {}
abstract class Atom <S extends Space<S,A>, A extends Atom<S, A>> {}
```

Comment: I would tend to make the order of parameters consisten.

Comment: Tom, your proposal works, but a very special thing is not working (very strange), please see the whole code in my 'answer', I hope you can tell me what's the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t try to solve that problem with generics. Instead, supply a Factory that always creates matching objects.

```
class UniverseFactory {
    public Space getSpace();
    public Atom getAtom();
}
```

You could then perform a type check in your implementations to ensure that only matching objects are used.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make parameterized types in Java know anything at all about their actual concrete type is to pass in a type parameter at construction:

```
public Foo<T>(class<T> klass, // other parameters
```

The meta answer is that circular type dependencies are questionable, and indicate a need to revisit your design. Generally, a better solution is to have a hierarchical dependency on a third type:

```
public class SomeAtom extends Atom<Something>
public class SomeSpace extends Space<Something>
```

The meta-meta answer is that "type safety" has its limitations, no matter what the language: http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.generics.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, "Tom Hawtin - tackline", I've incorporated your answer,
and it fits. Additionally, following code demonstrates the (slightly strange)
necessity to alter List type parameters (if you need List of atoms)

```
interface ISpace<S extends ISpace<S, A>, A extends IAtom<S, A>> {
    List<IAtom<? extends S, ? extends A>> getList();
}
interface IAtom<S extends ISpace<S, A>, A extends IAtom<S, A>> {
    S getSpace();
}

abstract class Space<S extends Space<S, A>, A extends Atom<S, A>>
    implements ISpace<S, A> {

    private final List<IAtom<? extends S, ? extends A>> atoms =
            new LinkedList<IAtom<? extends S, ? extends A>>();

    public Space() {
    }

    @Override
    public List<IAtom<? extends S, ? extends A>> getList() {
        return atoms;
    }
}

abstract class Atom<S extends Space<S, A>, A extends Atom<S, A>>
    implements IAtom<S, A> {

    private final S space;

    public Atom(S someSpace) {
        this.space = someSpace;

/// THIS WILL NOT WORK WITHOUT THOSE STRANGE LIST TYPE PARAMETERS
        space.getList().add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public S getSpace() {
        return space;
    }
}

class Space1 extends Space<Space1, Atom1> {
    public Space1() {
    }
}

class Atom1 extends Atom<Space1, Atom1> {
    public Atom1(Space1 someSpace) {
        super(someSpace);
    }
}
```

The idea behind the whole thing is:
I need element objects which know their container type-safely
and container objects which know their elements type-safely.

Comment: You'll probably also need to add a method to Atom: abstract A getThis(); and use that instead of the raw this.

Comment: As I said, without `? extends` it doesn't work.

And, `A getThis(){ return this; }` doesn't work either :(

Comment: YES! Found a solution:

`List<IAtom<? extends S, ? extends A>>`